# Data visualisation software for e-commerce platform

Tags: database, data-visualization, data-analysis, ecommerce

We have a data ware house(DB: PostgreSQL) which we use for data visualisation purposes using chartio .Can anyone suggest some good data visualisation softwares preferably open source or with less pricing which is suitable for an e-commerce company.

We have a website running on Magento.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

D3.js is a JavaScript library for manipulating documents based on data.
:
https://d3js.org/
:
but you need coding skills to use it